# Perturbation of recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, recursion

Let
$$x_{n+1} = a_n x_n + b_n$$
a recursion relation so that $x_n \rightarrow x$.

Let
$$y_{n+1} = a_n y_n + b_n + c_n$$
a perturbed relation.

I am looking for sufficient conditions on $c_n$ so that $y_n \rightarrow x$.

Is there a textbook/reference?

Thank you

Comment: do a, b change with $n$?

Comment: @user619894 yes

Comment: hint: If the limits exist, that implies something on the asymptotic behavior of $a,b,c$

Comment: @user619894 well I assume it means that $a_n \rightarrow 1$ and that $b_n, c_n \rightarrow 0$, but how does it help me to see what would make the limits identical? Thanks